Reference for a summation interchange formula
I need a good reference for the following summation interchange formula,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{m}a_{i, j}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\sum_{i=0}^{\min(j, n)}a_{i, j}$$
which is true for all $(m, n) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ with $m\geq n$.
I found it in Wikiversity french (here in the third example), but I need a good reference like a book or something like that.

It might be easier to prove it by induction.  If you draw the points that you sum over, they form a trapezoid.  The two sums correspond to summing horizontally and vertically.

Check this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816256/

Every term on LHS appears on RHS and vice versa, so the sums are equal.

what i need guys is a reference and not the proof

why do you need a reference? (It's not the sort of thing that needs referencing usually so I'm actually curious if it's a reference and not a proof that you need)
